# Durandal.js singleton not returning correct instance

Tags: javascript, durandal

I have one module called 'player', which controls a global player of my app. From another module, i'd like to know if the player is playing something. Inside the player module, I have an observable that returns the current status of the player. I have write both functions that check if the player is playing in different ways, but both always returns false from my another viewmodel.

player.js

```
define(['knockout', 'durandal/app'], function(ko, app) {
    ....
    var player = new Audio(),
        isPlaying = ko.observable(false),
        songIsPlaying = function() { return !player.paused }

     return {
      isPlaying: isPlaying,
      songIsPlaying: songIsPlaying
     }
})
```

home.js

```
define(['knockout', 'durandal/app', 'player'], function(ko, app, player) {
   function vm() {
      var self = this
      .....
      self.playOtherPlayer = function() {
        // this function plays another player, and I want to pause the global player if it's playing.
       console.log("global player is playing?")
       console.log(player.isPlaying())
       console.log(player.songIsPlaying())
      }

     return vm

   }
})
```

In both `console.log` inside `self.playOtherPlayer()`, it returns me `false`. I'm sure that the property `isPlaying()` from the player module is `true`, because I clicked on the play button and it changed to the pause button (I'm controlling the visibility of the play/pause buttons of the global player by this property). I tried so many ways to know if the player is paused but they all return me the wrong value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This statement confuses me: "I have one module called 'player', which controls a global player of my app." Is this global player instantiated somewhere else in your code? Because, is so, are you sure `var player = new Audio()` inside your module is referencing the same instance?

Comment: The player view is composed on shell.html. I'm not really worried about the player variable but I need to access the player's observables from other modules

Comment: Where do you change the value inside the observable isPlaying? It looks like you initialize it as false then output the value to the console log. Where  do you set it to true? Do you have an event listener somewhere?

Comment: I have a function called "play" that set isPlaying(true). I control the visibility of the play/pause buttons in the view with this observable, and it works. And of course, I have checked the value of isPlaying() after clicking on play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the correct instance of the viewmodel, you need to require it's moduleID. So you don't need to define the file in main.js. I just required 'viewmodels/player' and it gave me the correct instance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this will be working for you, but try to change your player module to return a singleton like this:

**Snippet code example:**

```
define([], function()
{
   var viewModel = function()
   {
      ......
   };

   return new viewModel();
});
```

**Full example code according from your code:**

```
define(['knockout', 'durandal/app'], function(ko, app) {
    var viewModel = function()
    {
       var self = this;

       ......

       var player = new Audio();

       self.isPlaying = ko.observable(false);

       self.songIsPlaying = function() {
           return ! player.paused;   
       }
    };

    return new viewModel();        
});
```